# i am gettting an error "No module named 'app.config'; 'app' is not a package"

Tags: python

```
import argparse
from collections import Counter
import time
from pyspin.spin import make_spin, Spin2
from helpers import display_results_histogram, get_number_of_frames, get_video_filenames, get_video_fps, \
    get_video_first_frame, print_finished_training_message, terminal_yes_no_question, show_final_match, \
    video_file_already_stabilised
from histogram import HistogramGenerator
from video_operations import VideoStabiliser
import app.config as config
def main():
    """
    Program entry point. Parses command line input to decide which phase of the system to run.
    :return: None
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--model",
                        help="The histogram model to use. Choose from the following options: 'rgb', 'hsv' or 'gray'. "
                             "Leave empty to train using all 3 histogram models.")          
    parser.add_argument("--mode",
                        required=True,
                        help="The mode to run the code in. Choose from the following options: 'train', 'test' or "
                            "'segment'.")
    parser.add_argument("--showhists",
                       action="store_true",
                        help="Specify whether you want to display each generated histogram.")
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug",
                        action="store_true",
                        help="Specify whether you want to print additional logs for debugging purposes.")
                        
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config.debug = args.debug
    config.mode = args.mode
    config.show_histograms = args.showhists
    config.model = args.model

    if config.mode == "train":
        off_line_colour_based_feature_extraction_phase()
    elif config.mode == "test":
        on_line_retrieval_phase()
    elif config.mode == "segment":
        database_preprocessing_phase()
    else:
        print("Wrong mode chosen. Choose from the following options: 'train', 'test' or 'segment'.")
        exit(0)


@make_spin(Spin2, "Generating histograms for database videos...".format(config.model))
def off_line_colour_based_feature_extraction_phase():
    """
    Generates and stores averaged greyscale, RGB and HSV histograms for all the videos in the directory-based database.
    :return: None
    """
    directory = "../footage/"
    files = get_video_filenames(directory)

    # start measuring runtime
    start_time = time.time()

    for file in files:
        if config.model == "gray":
            histogram_generator = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
            histogram_generator.generate_video_greyscale_histogram()
        elif config.model == "rgb":
            histogram_generator = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
            histogram_generator.generate_video_rgb_histogram()
        elif config.model == "hsv":
            histogram_generator = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
            histogram_generator.generate_video_hsv_histogram()
        else:
            histogram_generator_gray = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
            histogram_generator_gray.generate_video_greyscale_histogram()
            histogram_generator_rgb = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
            histogram_generator_rgb.generate_video_rgb_histogram()
            histogram_generator_hsv = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
            histogram_generator_hsv.generate_video_hsv_histogram()
    runtime = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
    print_finished_training_message(config.model, directory, runtime)


def on_line_retrieval_phase():
    """
    Prompts the user to stabilise and crop the query video before generating the same averaged greyscale, RGB and HSV
    histograms to compare with the database videos' previously stored histograms using distance metrics.
    :return: None
    """
    directory = "../recordings/"
    recordings = ["recording1.mp4", "recording2.mp4", "recording3.mp4", "recording4.mp4", "recording5.mp4",
                  "recording6.mp4", "recording7.mp4", "recording8.mp4"]
    mismatches_directory = "../recordings/mismatches/"
    mismatches = ["mismatch1.mp4", "mismatch2.mp4"]
    # 0: cloudy-sky, 1: seal, 2: butterfly (skewed), 3: wind-turbine, 4: ice-hockey, 5: jellyfish, 6: people-dancing,
    # 7: jellyfish (skewed)
    file = recordings[7]

    # ask user to stabilise the input query video or not
    is_stabilise_video = terminal_yes_no_question("Do you wish to stabilise the recorded query video?")
    stable_filename = "stable-" + file[:-4] + ".avi"  # the stable version of the video
    # yes: stabilise the video and use the stable .avi version
    if is_stabilise_video:
        if not video_file_already_stabilised(directory + stable_filename):
            VideoStabiliser(directory, "{}".format(file))
        print("\nStabilised version of query already found: '{}'".format(stable_filename))
        file = stable_filename
    # no: check if a version of the stabilised video doesn't already exist - use it if it does
    else:
        if video_file_already_stabilised(directory + stable_filename):
            file = stable_filename

    print("\nUsing query: '{}'".format(file))
    print("\nPlease crop the recorded query video for the signature to be generated.")

    if config.model == "gray":
        histogram_generator = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
        histogram_generator.generate_video_greyscale_histogram(is_query=True)
        histogram_generator.match_histograms()
    elif config.model == "rgb":
        histogram_generator = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
        histogram_generator.generate_video_rgb_histogram(is_query=True)
        histogram_generator.match_histograms()
    elif config.model == "hsv":
        histogram_generator = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
        histogram_generator.generate_video_hsv_histogram(is_query=True)
        histogram_generator.match_histograms()
    else:
        # calculate query histogram
        # greyscale
        histogram_generator_gray = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
        histogram_generator_gray.generate_video_greyscale_histogram(is_query=True)
        cur_reference_points = histogram_generator_gray.get_current_reference_points()
        # start measuring runtime (after manual cropping)
        start_time = time.time()
        # RGB
        histogram_generator_rgb = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
        histogram_generator_rgb.generate_video_rgb_histogram(is_query=True, cur_ref_points=cur_reference_points)
        # HSV
        histogram_generator_hsv = HistogramGenerator(directory, file)
        histogram_generator_hsv.generate_video_hsv_histogram(is_query=True, cur_ref_points=cur_reference_points)

        # calculate distances between query and DB histograms
        histogram_generator_gray.match_histograms(cur_all_model='gray')
        histogram_generator_rgb.match_histograms(cur_all_model='rgb')
        histogram_generator_hsv.match_histograms(cur_all_model='hsv')

        # Combine matches from all 3 histogram models to output one final result
        all_results = histogram_generator_hsv.get_results_array()  # array of all matches made (using weights)
        results_count = Counter(all_results)  # count the number of matches made for each video in all_results array
        # transform from count to percentage of matches made
        results_percentage = dict()
        for match in results_count:
            percentage = round((results_count[match] / len(all_results)) * 100.0, 2)
            results_percentage[match] = percentage
        display_results_histogram(results_percentage)
        print("Matches made: {}".format(results_count))
        print("% of matches made: {}".format(results_percentage))

        # find best result
        final_result_name = ""
        final_result_count = 0
        for i, r in enumerate(results_count):
            if i == 0:
                final_result_name = r
                final_result_count = results_count[r]
            else:
                if results_count[r] > final_result_count:
                    final_result_name = r
                    final_result_count = results_count[r]

        # print results
        runtime = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
        accuracy = final_result_count / len(all_results)
        get_video_first_frame(directory + file, "../results", is_query=True)
        get_video_first_frame("../footage/{}".format(final_result_name), "../results", is_result=True)
        show_final_match(final_result_name, "../results/query.png", "../results/result.png", runtime, accuracy)
        print_finished_training_message(final_result_name, config.model, runtime, accuracy)


def database_preprocessing_phase():
    """
    Applies a shot boundary detection algorithm to a video for segmentation.
    :return: None
    """
    directory = "../recordings/"
    video = "scene-segmentation.mp4"
    # directory = "/Volumes/ADAM2/"
    # movies = ["Inception (2010).mp4"]
    # video = movies[0]

    shot_boundary_detector = HistogramGenerator(directory, video)
    video_capture = shot_boundary_detector.get_video_capture()
    frame_count = get_number_of_frames(vc=video_capture)
    fps = get_video_fps(vc=video_capture)
    print("Total Frames: {}".format(frame_count))
    print("FPS: {}\n".format(fps))

    # start measuring runtime
    start_time = time.time()

    # start processing video for shout boundary detection
    print("Starting to process video for shot boundary detection...")
    shot_boundary_detector.rgb_histogram_shot_boundary_detection(threshold=7)

    # print final results
    runtime = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
    print("--- Number of frames in video: {} ---".format(frame_count))
    print("--- Runtime: {} seconds ---".format(runtime))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (mind the "minimal") and post the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your file, you have a line of Python like this:

`import app.config as config`

The error message is telling you that there is *no module* which means it cannot find a file called **app.py**. It is also telling you *app is not a package* which means there is no directory structure like this either:

```
app\
 - __init__.py
 - config.py
```

Because you haven't included those other files, it's hard to figure out what else is going wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/Adamouization/Content-Based-Video-Retrieval-Code    This is where i got the code and i installed all the pip requirements .. i have placed my main.py in the way you have told but i am still getting this error . Can you please help me ?

Comment: @NiveedhaM can you edit your question and show us what your directory folder looks like?